# How to compare multiple columns in two tables and find out the duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe

Dataframe 1

[image: Name]

Dataframe 2

[image]

ID column is not unique in the two tables. I want to compare all the columns in both the tables except ID's and print the unique rows

Expected output

[image]

I tried 'isin' function, but not working. Each dataframe size is 150000 and I removed duplicates in both the tables. Please advise how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.append to combine the dataframe, then use df.duplicated which will flag the duplicates.

```
df3 = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df4 = df3.duplicated(subset=['Team', 'name', 'Country', 'Token'], keep=False)
```